# Capacitor showing blank screen for react app in android studio

Tags: android, reactjs, progressive-web-apps, capacitor

I've tried setting up the below react apps locally and this is working as expected, however, when I try to install capacitor to these react apps and execute it from android studio. The app is opening up with a blank screen.

https://github.com/aditya-sridhar/simple-reactjs-app

https://github.com/arnab-datta/counter-app

Steps followed for adding a capacitor to react app and running it on android studio are as follows

1. Clone/Download the app from github
2. Do an npm install
3. Bring up the app locally to check if the app works from the browser
4. Bring down the app
5. Install npm install @capacitor/core
6. Install npm install @capacitor/cli --save-dev
7. Initialize Capacitor using npx cap init and proceed with default values
8. Install npm install @capacitor/android
9. Do npm run build
10. Add android platform using npx cap add android
11. Run android platform using npx cap run android

Note: While doing, npx cap run android I got an error and added local.properties in the generated Android folder.

Screen Image as follows

[image]

Comment: can you post the error message?

Comment: I don't see any error message anywhere

Comment: Looks like your web content isn't syncing over. Try `npx cap sync`.

Comment: let me give a try and get back to you.

Comment: @johnborges: I did give a try with npx cap sync and it didn't work. I still see the blank screen without app loading

Comment: Do you see any files in: android/app/src/main/assets?

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of investigations and reading various forums, I found that the following solution works for me both for ios and android.

Add the following hostname property under server section in the capacitor.config.ts file. set hostname to be 127.0.0.1 instead of url property set to http://localhost:8100 or http://127.0.0.1:8100

```
server: {
    hostname: '127.0.0.1',
    cleartext: true,
    allowNavigation: ['*'],
  }
```

Then run `npx cap sync`

Then the `ionic cap run android/ios` works fine for me.

To debug with live-reload, you can just run `ionic cap run -l android/ios --external`

Hope this helps